# Is it possible to accept and queue packet in iptables simultaneosly

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I want to accept the packets and analyze them too. The packet should go to its intended application and a copy should also be available in queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you queue the packet, the packets can be retrieved by a c program using libnetfilter_queue library. There you can issue the verdict NF_ACCEPT after analyzing the packet in the call back function.